# Conflict with preventDefault for dropdown menu with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have problem for several days with a currency dropdown menu. When I click on it, it doesn't open all the currencies possibilities. On the other hand, it works when I use preventDefault and stopPropagation but this comes into conflict with JS code that change the values on the page according to currency.

The dropdown doesn't work properly without `//e.preventDefault();` and `//e.stopPropagation();` and I'd rather not use it because it's in conflict with other JS that change the currency values. Is there a way to do that ?

```js
var $container = $('.maincar__currency'); // cache this for better performance as you use it multiple times

$container.click(function(e) {
  //e.preventDefault();
  //e.stopPropagation();
  $(this).toggleClass('expanded');
});

$(document).click(function() {
  $container.removeClass('expanded');
});
```

```css
.maincar__currency {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 32px;
  max-height: 32px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 6px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

input {
   display: none
}

.maincar__currency label {
  display: flex;
  width: 65px;
  height: 32px;
  padding: 6px;
  margin-right: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.maincar__currency label:first-child::after {
  content: "▾";
  margin-top: -1px;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.expanded {
  max-height: 132px;
  position: relative;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="maincar__currency" id="currency-drop-is">
  <label for="euro-radio-is">
    <div class="currency currency__euro">
      <input type="radio" name="currency-is" value="euro" id="euro-radio-is" class="euro_radio_is" checked>
      <span class="default">EUR</span>
    </div>
  </label>
  <label for="dollar-radio-is">
    <div class="currency currency__dollar">
      <input type="radio" name="currency-is" id="dollar-radio-is" class="dollar_radio_is" value="dollar">
      <span>USD</span>
    </div>
  </label>
  <label for="gbp-radio-is">
    <div class="currency currency__pound">
      <input type="radio" name="currency-is" id="gbp-radio-is" class="gbp_radio_is" value="gbp">
      <span>GBP</span>
    </div>
  </label>
  <label for="chf-radio-is">
    <div class="currency currency__chf">
      <input type="radio" name="currency-is" id="chf-radio-is" class="chf_radio_is" value="chf">
      <span>CHF</span>
    </div>
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Attach the close event to the document inside the open event handler, and use `.one('click', ...)` method instead of direct `click()` to unregister the event from the document after fired once.

Comment: `.one('click', ...)` only with the close event ?

Comment: It doesn't seem to work.